# Test onReceiveSSLError

Tags: android, webviewclient, sslerrorhandler

I fixed the vulnerability with the implementation of the WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler in my Android project but I would like to know how can I test it.

Previously my code was:

```
 @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.d("message","message");
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }
```

and after my fix is:

```
  @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.d("a message","a message");

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage("Certificate is invalid");
        builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                handler.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

For example can I modify the host in android emulator in order to point to a page that can throw ssl exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate an error by following steps:

1. Get webViewClient for your webview
2. Intercept the request by shouldInterceptRequest() method of webViewClient
3. Create a sslError and return from here
4. It will go to OnReceivedSslError method

Comment: Can you please me help how to create a sslErrror within shouldInterceptRequest() method? The definition of the method says that the return type should be WebResourceResponse.

Comment: Put a call to super.onReceivedSslError(view, new SslErrorHandler(), new SslError(SslError.SSL_INVALID, null)); in shouldInterceptRequest() method.
This will run your test scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried but it says that 'SslErrorHandler()' is not public in 'android.webkit.SslErrorHandler'. Cannot be accessed from outside package. Any ideas?

Comment: I just checked. Keep it simple. Just call super.onReceivedSslError(view, null, null); 
 in shouldInterceptRequest() method. This will run your test scenario.